# Соединение GET-параметров двух форм

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть 2 формы, одна из которых - это фильтр товаров, вторая - сортировка товаров.

Фильтр товаров (небольшая часть, чтобы не захламлять):

```
     <form method="GET">
                                    <div class="row clearfix">
    
                                        <div class="form-group col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="field-inner">
                                                <div class="field-icon"><span class="flaticon-boat-2"></span></div>
                                                <?php if($product_type) : ?>
                                                <select class="custom-select-box" name="pa_yacht-type">
                                                    <option value="0"><?php pll_e('Yacht Type'); ?></option>
                                                    <?php foreach ($product_type as $item) :?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $item-> slug?>" <?php if( isset( $_GET[ 'pa_yacht-type' ] ) && $item->slug == $_GET[ 'pa_yacht-type' ] ) : ?>selected<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $item-> name;?></option>
                                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                                </select>
                                                <?php endif;?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-xl-3 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="field-inner">
                                            <div class="field-icon"><span class="flaticon-calendar"></span></div>
                                              <?php if($year) : ?>
                                             <input type="text" name="min_year" value="<?php echo isset( $_GET[ 'min_year' ] ) ? strval( $_GET[ 'min_year' ] ) : 'Minimum Year' ?>" placeholder="Minimum Year">
                                             <?php endif;?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-xl-3 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="field-inner">
                                            <div class="field-icon"><span class="flaticon-calendar"></span></div>
                                              <?php if($year) : ?>
                                             <input type="text" name="max_year" value="<?php echo isset( $_GET[ 'max_year' ] ) ? strval( $_GET[ 'max_year' ] ) : 'Maximum Year' ?>" placeholder="Maximum Year">
                                             <?php endif;?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
<div class="form-group col-xl-3 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12">                  
                                    <button type="submit" class="theme-btn"><span class="btn-title"><span class="icon flaticon-magnifying-glass"></span><?php pll_e('Find Your Yacht'); ?></span></button></div></form>
```

И сортировка товаров:

```
                <div class="filter-box">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="field-inner">
                            <form class="woocommerce-ordering" action="" method="get">
                            <select name="orderby" class="orderby" aria-label="Shop order">
                                <option value="lenght"><?php pll_e('Sorting by Lenght');?></option>
                                <option value="price"><?php pll_e('Sorting by Price');?></option>
                                <option value="year"><?php pll_e('Sorting by Year');?></option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что когда я активировал фильтр и решаю сделать сортировку, то  в URL убираются get-параметры фильтра и добавляются гет-параметры сортировки.

Как сделать так, чтобы параметры фильтра не чистились, а к ним добавлялись параметры сортировки?

Comment: В чем проблема обернуть это в одну форму? иначе делайте свою функция отправки данных на js, например ajax =)

Comment: В одну форму можно, но людям непонятно будет))
Ок, за совет спасибо) Но хотелось бы на php, с js особо не дружу :)

Comment: Не понятно что? форма - не визуальный компонент, а невидимый, объединяющий в одну сущьность несколько разных полей.... ```<form class="woocommerce-ordering" action="" method="get">``` - вот этот компонент растянуть на оба поля ввода, чтобы они оказались оба внутри формы.
p/s/ php не особо имеет отношение к фронту(к стороне пользователя), первый вариант html, второй js.... для пхп тут места нет совсем